# Connecting Ruby(Rails) to Nodejs through a pipe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, pipe

I have a rails app that needs to make use of a Javascript library on the server.  Up until now I have been running system commands from rails to nodejs whenever this is necessary.  However, I have a particularly computationally intensive task that has made it necessary to cache data to speed it up.  I also have to pass large inputs to the node program.  As a result I've hit the buffer size of inputs to the node program.  I am currently just sending it to separate node processes multiple times in chunks small enough to fit in the buffer, but this is causing performance problems because I now no longer get to take advantage of caching over as many runs.   I would like to use a pipe to do this, but my pipe hits the buffer as well, and I don't know how to empty it.  So far I have...

```
#ruby file
output=[]
node_pipe=IO.popen("nodejs /home/user/node_program.js","w+")

10_000.times do |time|
  node_pipe.write("a lot of stuff")
  #here I would like to read contents and push contents to output array but still be      
  #able to write to the same process in the next loop to take advantage of the cache
end

//node_program.js
var input=process.stdin;
var cache={};
input.resume();
input.on('data',function(chunk){
  cache[chunk]=library_function(chunk);
  console.log(String(other_library_function(chunk)));
}
```

Any suggestions?

```
`
```